# Thymeleaf sec:authentication tag not displaying role

Tags: java, spring, authentication, thymeleaf, roles

I'm trying to access a user's role and privileges in Thymeleaf with the sec:authentication="principal.authorities" tag so I can control what is displayed to the user. My goal was to retrieve either 'ROLE_ADMIN' or 'ROLE_USER', but it appears to be retrieving the three privileges associated with that role instead, '[CHANGE_PASSWORD_PRIVILEGE, READ_PRIVILEGE, WRITE_PRIVILEGE]'.

I'm hoping someone can help further my understanding of the Principal object and the User class that implements UserDetails from the springframework. I'm specifically interested in the authorities attribute and how I might retrieve a user's 'ROLE' from it. This is my first time implementing this so I'm sure there is more for me to learn. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Note* This is my first post so it appears I'm limited on images. I will try to do my best with text for now.

**Current Results and Implementation**

This is what renders on my profile.html page.

Current user roles: [CHANGE_PASSWORD_PRIVILEGE, READ_PRIVILEGE, WRITE_PRIVILEGE]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/web/thymeleaf/layout"
      xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/extras/spring-security" layout:decorator="layout">
<head>
    <title>Profile</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1 layout:fragment="header">Profile</h1>
<div layout:fragment="content" class="container">

    Current user name:
    <span sec:authentication="principal.username">User</span>

    <br/>
    Current user name 2: 
    <span sec:authentication="name">User</span>

    <br/>
    <br/>
    Current user roles:
    <span sec:authentication="principal.authorities">[ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN]</span>

    <br/>
    <div sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">
        Current user roles 2:
        <span sec:authentication="authorities">[ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN]</span>
    </div>
    

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**This is MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService**

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
    
    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());
    
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    
    @Autowired
    private LoginAttemptService loginAttemptService;
    
    @Autowired
    private HttpServletRequest request;
    
    
    public MyUserDetailsService() {
        super();        
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(final String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        try {
            final User user = userRepository.findByEmail(email);
            if (user == null) {
                throw new UsernameNotFoundException("No user found with username: " + email);
            }
            log.info("User: " + user.getEmail() + " Password: " + user.getPassword() + "Role: " + user.getRoles());
            return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getEmail(), user.getPassword(), true, true, true, true, getAuthorities(user.getRoles()));
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    private Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities(Collection<Role> roles) {
        return getGrantedAuthorities(getPrivileges(roles));

    }

    private List<String> getPrivileges(Collection<Role> roles) {
        final List<String> privileges = new ArrayList<>();
        final List<Privilege> collection = new ArrayList<>();
        for (final Role role : roles) {
            collection.addAll(role.getPrivileges());
        }
        for (final Privilege item : collection) {
            privileges.add(item.getName());
        }
        return privileges;
    }
    
    private List<GrantedAuthority> getGrantedAuthorities(List<String> privileges) {
        final List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String privilege : privileges) {
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(privilege));
        }
        return authorities;
    }
    
}
```

This is what is displayed when I log the user.getRole() from my loadUserByName method.
"[Role [id=4, name=ROLE_ADMIN]]"

**Maven**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

**User.class**

```
 * @param authorities the authorities that should be granted to the caller if they
 * presented the correct username and password and the user is enabled. Not null.
 *
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException if a <code>null</code> value was passed either as
 * a parameter or as an element in the <code>GrantedAuthority</code> collection
 */
public User(String username, String password, boolean enabled,
        boolean accountNonExpired, boolean credentialsNonExpired,
        boolean accountNonLocked, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {

    if (((username == null) || "".equals(username)) || (password == null)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "Cannot pass null or empty values to constructor");
    }

    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
    this.enabled = enabled;
    this.accountNonExpired = accountNonExpired;
    this.credentialsNonExpired = credentialsNonExpired;
    this.accountNonLocked = accountNonLocked;
    this.authorities = Collections.unmodifiableSet(sortAuthorities(authorities));
}
```

Comment: Why are you creating the `SimpleGrantedAuthority` from the `Privile` values? Have you tried using the `Role` values instead?

Comment: I have passed a String "ROLE_ADMIN" as a hard coded value into `new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN")` and the `sec:authorize` tag in my html will works as expected. I think I was under the assumption that the `authorities` attribute in the User.class would have a collection of both the `Roles` and `Privileges` and that the  `principal.authorities` would be able to identify which `Roles` were there. However, I think I'm realizing that I'm not actually storing the `Roles` in there and only the `Privileges` are being passed.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the `Privileges` into the `SimpleGrantedAuthority` constructor while you should pass in the `Roles`.

Check the actual String value you pass into `SimpleGrantedAuthority`, this should match with what you use in `<div sec:authorize="hasRole('ADMIN')">` or `<div sec:authorize="hasAuthority('ROLE_ADMIN')">` (There is a difference if you need to prefix with `ROLE_` or not)

Comment: Wim, thank you for your replies! I did vote for your answer, but I'm new so it won't count it until my rep increases. You definitely nail the problem I'm having and provide a good solution.